# "do_every_frame" not available in a lua script for x-plane 12

Tags: linux, lua, xplane

I'm trying to run a simple plugin for x-plane 12 (on Linux Mint) but I'm getting this error in the console:

`attempt to call global 'do_every_frame' (a nil value)`

I tried running the script from  'X-Plane 12/Aircraft/Laminar Research/Beechcraft Baron 58/plugins/xlua/scripts'
or from '/X-Plane 12/Resources/plugins' (the script actually won't even load or run from this location)

```
-- Variables to track time
local elapsedTime = 0
--local timeToFailure = 300 -- Time in seconds before the first engine failure
local timeToFailure = 120


-- Function called on each frame
function beachBaronRandomEngineFailurePlugin.onFlightLoop()
    -- Update elapsed time
    elapsedTime = elapsedTime + get_frame_time()

    -- Check if it's time for an engine failure
    if elapsedTime >= timeToFailure then
        -- Randomly select an engine to fail
        local engineToFail = math.random(1, 2)

        -- Check if the selected engine is running and shut it down
        if engineToFail == 1 and getdref("sim/flightmodel/engine/ENGN_running[0]") == 1 then
            command_once("sim/operation/failures/eng_fail_ignition[0]")
        elseif engineToFail == 2 and getdref("sim/flightmodel/engine/ENGN_running[1]") == 1 then
            command_once("sim/operation/failures/eng_fail_ignition[1]")
        end

        -- Reset elapsed time for the next failure
        elapsedTime = 0
        -- Set a new time for the next failure (you can modify this as needed)
        timeToFailure = math.random(600, 1200) -- Random time between 10 to 20 minutes
    end
end

-- Function to initialize the plugin
function beachBaronRandomEngineFailurePlugin.init()
    -- Set a callback for the flight loop
    --do_every_frame("beachBaronRandomEngineFailurePlugin.onFlightLoop()")

    -- Print a message after setting the callback
    print("Callback set!")
end

    -- Print the status of do_every_frame
    if do_every_frame then
        print("do_every_frame exists!")
    else
        print("do_every_frame does not exist!")
    end

-- Call the initialization function
beachBaronRandomEngineFailurePlugin.init()
```